# How to get data of grouped column in Angular UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can we get the data of all rows in a grouped column in Angular UI Grid?

For example, in the official [Grouping Tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping), how to get all the company names in the 'Company' column.

I was able to get the aggregated value of grouped row by using the following code:

```
for (var i = 0, l = $scope.gridRows.length; i<l; i += 1){
    console.log($scope.gridRows[i].treeNode.aggregations[COLUMN_INDEX].value);
}
```

But doesn't work for the 'Company' column, since their is no aggregate value for that column, and what I want is all the company's names.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key knowledge here is that `$scope.gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree` holds the rendered tree, and the structure of that tree is described in http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.treeBase.grid:treeBase

What I think you want to do is to walk that tree and extract the information you want.

So really you want to navigate that tree pulling out `row.entity.company`.  What I'm not clear on is why that would make sense - presumably you actually want to get at the specific companies under a given tree node, or the companies that are currently visible.

If you want the companies that are visible, you could check `row.visible` as you walk the tree.  If you want those under a specific node, you need a way to know which node you want.  If you have a gridRow that you're trying to extract for, you can then use `row.treeNode.children` to get at the subset of the tree that is under that specific row.